# Dynamically add, link and render a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a tag element `popup-window` in my markup that I process with a respective directive.
If I want to have more such widgets that I want to show or hide in different places, I need now to put all these elements in my page markup that I am not sure looks clean and is the best way. So it looks like this:

```
<popup-window></popup-window>
<details-window></details-window>
<share-widget></share-widget>
<twitter-stream></twitter-stream>
```

Is it possible to run directives dynamically on the elements that I add on the fly in the DOM? I want to make the markup clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $compile service to compile templates containing directives and append that to your page. That is, if you don't want to add `<twitter-stream></twitter-stream>` until someone clicks on a "Add twitter stream" button, you could do something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    }]);
    myApp.directive('twitterStream', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.append('<p>A tweet: ' + Math.random() + '</p>')
            }
        }
    });
    myApp.directive('createTwitterStreamButton', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<button ng-click="add()">Add twitter stream</button>',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.add = function() {
                    var directiveElement = $compile('<twitter-stream></twitter-stream>')(scope);
                    directiveElement.insertAfter(elem);
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <create-twitter-stream-button></create-twitter-stream-button>
</body>
</html>
```